# Raise exception but not a 500 code - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to wrap a action within a transaction, but transaction don't work unless an exception is thrown. So, basically I'm trying to raise an error but have it continue on to the page with raising a 500. Here is what I'm current doing.

```
def update
    resource.transaction do
      super do |user|
        if membership_params.present?
          ToggleAlertEmails.perform(user: current_user, params: membership_params)
        end

        if user.errors[:current_password].present?
          raise IncorrectError
          render :edit
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

That raise this error `RegistrationsController::IncorrectError:`

That seems correct but can I just render the edit action instead of the 500 page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `rescue_from` in your controller

```
rescue_from RegistrationsController::IncorrectError, with: :show_500

def show_500(exception)
  @exception = exception
  render :template => "/500.html", :status => 500
end
```

Comment: Could I do something like this - `render :edit, status: 200`?

Comment: @Bitwise Sure, `render` generally accept five options: :content_type, :layout, :location, :status, :formats.